# Python: faster way of counting occurences in numpy arrays (large dataset)

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, statistics

I am new to Python. I have a `numpy.array` which size is `66049x1` (66049 rows and 1 column). The values are sorted smallest to largest and are of `float` type, with some of them being repeated.

I need to determine the frequency of occurrences of each value (the number of times a given value is **equalled but not surpassed**, e.g. **X<=x in statistical terms**), in order to later plot the Sample Cumulative Distribution Function.

The code I am currently using is as follows, but it is extremely slow, as it has to loop `66049x66049=4362470401` times. Is there any way to augment the speed of such piece of code? Will perhaps the use of `dictionaries` help in any way? Unfortunately I cannot change the size of the arrays I am working with.

```
+++Function header+++
...
...
directoryPath=raw_input('Directory path for native csv file: ')
csvfile = numpy.genfromtxt(directoryPath, delimiter=",")
x=csvfile[:,2]
x1=numpy.delete(x, 0, 0)
x2=numpy.zeros((x1.shape[0]))
x2=sorted(x1)
x3=numpy.around(x2, decimals=3)
count=numpy.zeros(len(x3))

#Iterates over the x3 array to find the number of occurrences of each value
for i in range(len(x3)):
    temp=x3[i]
    for j in range(len(x3)):
       if (temp<=x3[j]):
           count[j]=count[j]+1

#Creates a 2D array with (value, occurrences)
    x4=numpy.zeros((len(x3), 2))
    for i in range(len(x3)):
    x4[i,0]=x3[i]
    x4[i,1]=numpy.around((count[i]/x1.shape[0]),decimals=3)
...
...
+++Function continues+++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100000,1))

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

cnt = Counter(df[0])

df_p = pd.DataFrame(cnt, index=['data'])

df_p.T.plot(kind='hist')

plt.show()
```

That whole script took a very short period to execute (~2s) for (`100,000x1)` array. I didn't time, but if you provide the time it took to do yours we can compare.

[image]

I used `[Counter][2]` from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html) to count the number of occurrences, my experiences with it have always been great (timewise). I converted it into [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to plot and used `T` to transpose.

Your data does replicate a bit, but you can try and refine it some more. As it is, it's pretty fast.

**Edit**

Create CDF using `cumsum()`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100000,1))

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

cnt = Counter(df[0])

df_p = pd.DataFrame(cnt, index=['data']).T


df_p['cumu'] = df_p['data'].cumsum()

df_p['cumu'].plot(kind='line')

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

For [`scatter()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-plot) plot you must specify the (x,y) explicitly. Also, calling `df_p['cumu']` will result in a `Series`, not a `DataFrame`.

To properly display a scatter plot you'll need the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100000,1))

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

cnt = Counter(df[0])

df_p = pd.DataFrame(cnt, index=['data']).T


df_p['cumu'] = df_p['data'].cumsum()

df_p.plot(kind='scatter', x='data', y='cumu')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! My time estimate is around 150 minutes for an entire array, and it is a tragedy, as you might imagine. I even tried with a shortened array (10000 elements instead of 66049) and it still takes ages. I think the next step is summing up the occurrences for each bin to get to plot the CDF, but this will produce a stepwise function. Any suggestion which does not involve a histogram? I will also have to plot the sample distribution...

Comment: Look at my edit and let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: The bins approach produces a discretized Probability Distribution Function, which looks like a stairway. Instead, given my high number of values, I would like to have something continuous-like, and this is why I tend to stay clear of the bins approach. But if this is significantly faster than my approach, I think I will give it a try! Thoughts?

Comment: I didn't use bins at all, I created the cumulative sum to represent the CDF, however I see a mistake where I didn't normalize it. The histogram I showed earlier was just proof of concept, didn't actually use its values

Comment: This solution is way faster than mine, so +1(000)! Anyhow, I'm having problems with the plot kind. I'd like to specify `df_p['cumu'].plot(kind='scatter')` but I get: `ValueError: plot kind 'scatter' can only be used for data frames`. How to work this around? And would `df_p['cumu']=df_p['data'].cumsum()/len(x3)` normalize my Y axis with respect to the total number of values that I have (`len(x3)`)? Sorry for asking but I am not familiar with `pandas`. Thanks!

Comment: Uhm, I might have made a mistake in my last comment, so I apologise (anyhow, your reply is another chance for me to learn). What if I wanted my CDF to be plotted as an ensemble of points rather than a continuous line, given that my dataset is huge but discrete? Thanks for your patience and dedication!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91640/discussion-between-leb-and-francesco-castellani).

Comment: Uhm, I thought I had sorted this out, but unfortunately not. The line df_p.plot(kind='scatter',x='data',y='cumu') does not give me anything that is S-shaped, as a CDF is. Sorry to bother you again. The x-axis should show my values (which are float and range 0 to 1), whereas the y-axis should show the normalized sum of all values that are <= to a given value. Instead, on the x-axis I get the number of occurrences of each value...what is wrong?

Comment: That's not the CDF, my last edit (Edit 2) is to show you how to plot as a scatter. You need to change `df_p.plot()` to `plt.scatter(df_p.index , df_p['cumu']/100000)` like I mentioned in chat.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but what if I wanted to transform df_p['cumu'] into a 66049x2 numpy array, with headers? I must print its values to a csv file later on. Thanks!

Comment: Create a new question since this post relates only to your original one. This prevents multiple questions to be answered in one post.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `np.where` and then count the length of the obtained vector of indices:

```
indices = np.where(x3 <= value)
count = len(indices[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

If efficiency counts, you can use the numpy function bincount, which need integers :

```
import numpy as np
a=np.random.rand(66049).reshape((66049,1)).round(3)
z=np.bincount(np.int32(1000*a[:,0]))
```

it takes about 1ms.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
# for counting a single value
mask = (my_np_array == value_to_count).astype('uint8')
# or a condition
mask = (my_np_array <= max_value).astype('uint8')

count = np.sum(mask)
```